# Docker trying to push 900MB to aws ec2 container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, dockerfile

I've created a docker image locally, and it's about **900MB**. I've setup **AWS container service** and I'm now trying push my docker image to it. My docker image is a node (v6) application.

It's taking too long and I feel like I'm doing something wrong here? It shouldn't be trying to push 900MB (the size of my image) should it?

Is there a way to simply push my **Dockerfile** to **AWS** and have it pull my code from github, build the image on the server, and then run it?

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:6.2.0

# Create app directory inside the container
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 7000

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

The code which I'm running to push my docker image is the following:

```
docker push <id.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/name:latest
```

Before this I ran the following:

```
aws ecr get-login --region ap-southeast-2

docker login -u AWS -p <token> -e none <aws_url>
```

Comment: Note that Docker requires you to push the content of all layers, even those from a base image, in an effort to make you "prove" that you have them, preventing you from gaining access to base images you shouldn't have permission to. Run `docker inspect` to see the sizes of your layers.

Comment: So basically, I'll just have to wait it out for docker images to upload? @JonathonReinhart Even if I only change 1/2 files and want to deploy a bug fix, will I have to wait for the whole 900MBs to upload again?

Comment: @James111 no, that's just the first push, every other push will only push the new layers. It's similar to how git works, first time you pull down the entire repo, every time after that you just get new commits.